# i dont know why but i am getting a turtle import error and i need assistance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Ummmm so I'm trying to make this pong game but it keeps giving me this error and idk why. The ide is saying everything is fine but I get the error when running it. help pls.

Error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'

The code is a bit long so I can't really paste it here but I am using pycharm for IDE

Comment: Hello, and welcome! We're going to need more information to help you - are you following some sort of guide you can link us to, or are you using a certain toolset? What IDE are you using? Can you give us an example of your code?

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a more thorough guide of how to help us help you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you forgot to install it with pip or deleted it.

- windows + R
- type `cmd`
- Enter
- type `pip install turtle`
- Enter

Comment: i installed tkinter and turtle with pip

Comment: **This is wrong. `turtle` should be part of the standard library, and `pip` cannot be used to install any standard library components. `pip install turtle` will attempt to install a completely unrelated package that is many years out of date and is 2.x-specific.**